# Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA unexpected result

Tags: google-sheets

I have been attempting to create a Google Sheets formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(INDEX(P2:T,SMALL(IF(T2:T = "Sent",ROW(P2:P)-1),1))))
```

to fulfill the following requirement:

Look up the first result of cells containing the word "Sent" in the T column, and display contents of the T column of the same row.

But instead it's not giving me any result, just blank.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Use Filter function which will be faster than array formula.

Comment: You can't use index in arrayformula ! The INDEX function is one that does not support "iteration" over an array. So use Filter, or use arrayformula and matches/hlookup/vlookup ... Please, provide a link to a copy of your sheet.